# How to handle ActionBar's icons visibility when using SearchView

Tags: android, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

Well, what I want is to:

- Initialize ActionBar with all items, except "searchSettings";
- When click on the Search icon, searchSettings appears and the rest of the icons disappear;
- When close the search EditText (pressing device's back button or ActionBar's back button), ActionBar returns to its original state (all icons appearing, except "searchSettings").

My actual code is the following:

(I've imported `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` instead of `android.widget.SearchView`. When I was using `android.widget.SearchView` this worked fine but other things don't)

```
private MenuItem searchIteam, searchSettings;
private SearchView searchView;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menuMain);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchSettings = menu.findItem(R.id.action_searchSettings);
    searchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchSettings.setVisible(false); // hide searchSettings Item when Menu is created

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            (...)

            return false;
        }
    });

    // Detect SearchView icon clicks
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setItemsVisibility(menuMain, item, false);
            searchSettings.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    // Detect SearchView close
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); //shouldn't this reload the Action Bar as it was when onCreate?
            return true;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

private void setItemsVisibility(Menu menu, MenuItem exception, boolean visible) {
    for (int i=0; i<menu.size(); ++i) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item != exception) item.setVisible(visible);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    supportInvalidadeOptionsMenu();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

This code doesn't work, when I press "back" first time, it only closes the Search's EditText and the icons don't change. If I press back again, the Activity goes a level up but I can see the icons getting as the beginning (getting as they should when I pressed "back" for the first time) a little while before the Activity close...

**--- EDIT ---**

Currently, if I click on Search ActionBar Icon, and then begin to press "Back Button" repeatedly, the following happens:

- 1st pressing: the keyboard hides, but the search EditText is still open;
- 2nd pressing: the searching ends (search EditText closes and the normal activity's content is shown);
- 3rd pressing: the activity closes.

Then, for testing purposes, I did this:

```
boolean pressed1, pressed2, pressed3;

searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pressed1 = false;
            pressed2 = false;
            pressed3 = false;
            setItemsVisibility(menuMain, item, false);
            searchSettings.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!pressed1) {
        pressed1 = true;
    }
    else if(!pressed2) {
        pressed2 = true;
    }
    else if(!pressed3) {
        pressed3 = true;
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And now, what happens is:

- 1st pressing: the keyboard hides, but the search EditText is still open;
- 2nd pressing: the searching ends (search EditText closes and the normal activity's content is shown);
- 3rd pressing: nothing happens;
- 4th pressing: nothing happens;
- 5th pressing: the ActionBar reloads as I wanted;
- 6th pressing: the activity closes;

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

Then I've changed to this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!pressed1) {
        pressed1 = true;
        onBackPressed();
    }
    else if(!pressed2){
        pressed2 = true;
        onBackPressed();
    }
    else if(!pressed3){
        pressed3 = true;
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

What is happening now is:

- 1st pressing: the keyboard hides, but the search EditText is still open;
- 2nd pressing: the searching ends (search EditText closes and the normal activity's content is shown);
- 3rd pressing: the ActionBar reloads as I wanted;
- 4th pressing: the activity closes;

**--- EDIT 3 --- (SOLUTION) ---**

I guess that the methods `setOnSearchClickListener` and `setOnCloseListener` are from `android.widget.SearchView`... As I've imported `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` instead, I've changed them to:

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem,
            new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    setItemsVisibility(menu, searchItem, false);
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Now it's working just fine (:

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get you right: the first time you press BACK, the keyboard gets hidden. The second time you press BACK, the app quits.

If this is the case, then everything works fine. Becuase this is what super.onBackPressed() is supposed to do. It will try to hide the keyboard if it's shown. If not, it will try to go the previous activity. If there is none, it will quit the app.

So what you need to do is play with the onBackPressed() method. Basically, you don't necessarily need to call the super method if you are sure what you should do.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if ( isSearching) {
        supportInvalidadeOptionsMenu();
        isSearching = false;     
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

So now, when never you press BACK button, the activity will check if isSearching, and decide to re-render the action bar or take its normal actions as usual.

You'll need to add some logic to set the boolean flag isSearching, for example, set isSearching to true when clicking the Search.

I 'm not sure if supportInvalidadeOptionsMenu() would reset your action bar. Anyway, you can adjust the visibility for each view instead.

Comment: Thanks, Cris! But I'm afraid you got it wrong... The first time that I press Back, the keyboard hides (ok, that's normal), after that, the "first time" that I press Back, the search ends but the icons doesn't reload... I've already tried manually setting visibility instead of using "supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()" and it still doesn't work ;(. If I use your method, it works pressing Back again after all that... It won't go back to previous activity but doesn't work on the first press either =/

Comment: It is because you called the super.onBackPressed(), and the super method will quit the app unless you do it as I tell you. The super.onBackPressed() is called EVERYTIME when you press back button in you code, and that's the problem.

Comment: You need to tell the onBackPressed() method exactly what is supposed to happen. if keyboard is shown, then use super.onBackPressed(), else if is Searching, then re-render action bar, do not call super.onBackPressed(), else call super.onBackPressed(). And you should go to previous activity in this case.

Comment: After doing all that, I don't know why, it still takes 2 "Back Hits" to reload the ActionBar =/

Comment: Please check the order of your if statements in the onBackPressed() method, you may not be hitting the desired clause before returning. If you still have problem, please post your code.

Comment: Please take a look on my Edit and Edit 2

Comment: glad you find the solution, but calling onBackPressd() inside onBackPressed doesn't make sense. It's recursive call. And I've made a mistake on hiding the keyboard, it did not hit the onBackPressed() method actually. So the first BACK press would always hide the keyboard and do nothing else.

Comment: I've called onBackPressed() inside onBackPressed to simulate next back button's pressing, just for testing... I did not notice that the first back pressing would just close the keyboard either... Thank you for the help, sir!